# PBRequester failed with Error in iOS app

Tags: ios, nsurlerrordomain, pbrequester

I am facing some strange problem in my iOS app. When my app is open and the user presses the sleep/wake button, app calls

```
applicationWillResignActive
applicationDidEnterBackground
```

When user right swipe to unlock the screen , app calls

```
applicationWillEnterForeground
applicationDidBecomeActive
```

After that, it prints the following error in console:

```
PBRequester failed with Error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo=0x1cdfbc00 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://gsp10-ssl.apple.com/use, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://gsp10-ssl.apple.com/use, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found., NSUnderlyingError=0x1cddca10 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found."}
```

I know this error is stating that the specified host name was not found. But which host name? Is it https://gsp10-ssl.apple.com/use or the hostname which I am using for web services?

How can I debug this error, and identify its origin?

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this? I'm also seeing this problem. a bit of reference, I'm also using the Parse SDK. Not sure if this has anything to do with it but if I had to guess I would say no.

Comment: I didn't get any solution to above problem....

Comment: Dang I'm running into something similar except it's Code=-1001 "The request timed out."

Comment: hmm, I ran into code=-1003 as well. Anyone has more info on this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I integrated the parse.com framework into my app.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
  PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
  [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
  [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
  [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}
```

After I moved this two code block from the AppDelegate into my main ViewController file the error message was gone... Maybe it helps you...

Answer (score 2):

I had similar error. I have a application with MKMapView. While I was testing application I intentionally disconnect device Wifi to see app behaviour, in debug i see error:

```
PBRequester failed with Error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo=0x18e4fac0 {NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://gsp10-ssl.apple.com/use, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSUnderlyingError=0x18e51690 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.", NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://gsp10-ssl.apple.com/use}
```

At this point device was trying to connect 3G because device had "Mobile Data" enabled. I also had no credit for a 3G connection. I suppose that was the source of specifically this error (no credit for 3G), because when I disabled "Mobile Data" I was, already, receiving another error, also from PBRequester

```
PBRequester failed with Error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo=0x188e4b00 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://gsp10-ssl.apple.com/use, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://gsp10-ssl.apple.com/use, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, NSUnderlyingError=0x18d78410 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."}
```

I tend to blame MKMapView object for raising these errors, as it needs continuously an active connection to retrieve map layers/titles. While application have other active screens ( with no MKMapView), there is no error raised.